# Center and increase size of text using GitHub MarkDown in summary block without new line (aligned with the summary arrow)

Tags: html, css, markdown, summary, github-flavored-markdown

I would like to create a summary in a README.md markdown file from GitHub with increased size of text, centered, and in the same line as the arrow that `<summary>` creates.

Currently I am able to create the summary but with small text and not centered. If I try to center it with `<center>` or `align="center"`, or increase the size of the text with `<h3> My projects: </h3>` the summary appears in a new row, not aligned with the arrow that `<summary>` creates:

- Without trying to align:

```markdown
<details>
    <summary>
         My projects: 
    </summary>
    my user stats
</details>
```

[image: summary line without centering]

- With aligning:

```markdown
<details>
    <summary>
        <center> My projects: </center>
    </summary>
    my user stats
</details>
```

[image: summary line with centering but incorrecly rendered]

[I have been researching the problem and it seems that avoiding the creation of a new line in GitHub Markdown is a thing that some people have been struggling with](https://gist.github.com/scmx/eca72d44afee0113ceb0349dd54a84a2).

So basically what I need is

```markdown
<details>
    <summary>
         My projects (this text has to be aligned with the arrow, centered and with increased font size in GitHub markdown): 
    </summary>
    my user stats
</details>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You probably won't be able to get this working. GitHub enforces most of the CSS that gets used to render its READMEs.